# Why doesn't this twitter iframe float right?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
      background-color:olive;
      margin:0;
    }



    nav {
      background-color:aqua;
      position:sticky;
      top:0;
      border:1px solid red;

    }
    
    #container{
      max-height:1800px;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;

      
    }

     #container >a {
      
      background-color:chocolate;
      padding:7px;
      border-radius:10px; 
      text-decoration:none;
    }

    #container > a:hover{
      opacity:0.5;
    }

    #item-2, #item-3, #item-1, #item-0 {
     align-self:flex-start;
     margin-top:5px;
    }

    #logout {
     margin-left:auto;
    }

    .bonus {
       margin-left:10px;
     }
    /* nav is finally done after 1.5 hours lol and another 30mins  */

    #bear-nest {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      justify-content:flex-end;
      align-items:center;
    }

    .theme {
      border-radius:20%;
     display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
    }


    #bear{
      text-align:center;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      width:70%;
    }

    hr {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .font {
      font: 24px "Pontano Sans", sans-serif;
    }

    .contacts {
      background-color:#86efa0;
    }

   
     .onlyh3{
    color: #333;
    font: normal 18px "Pontano Sans", arial, sans-serif;
   margin-top:50px;
  }
      

    #fullcontacts  p {
      margin-left:2px;
       color: #2c2b2b;
      font: normal 12px arial;
      line-height: normal;
      line-height: 18px;
    }

    .pls {
      margin-left:20px;
    }

    .kenya {
      margin: 30 30;
    }

    .note {
      width:30%;
      margin-top:30px;
    }
    .flexbox{
      width:30%;
      max-height:400px;
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
    }

   input {
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-bottom:13px;
   }

   .forms {
    width:30%;
   }
   .float {
    float:right;
   }
```

```html
<body>

  <img src=https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531870972494-627796a756dc?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=72a43beae93d56392f98f6eda2cdd8cb&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 width="100%" height="150" "border-radius:40px">
<nav>
  <div id="main-content">
  <div id="container" >
    <a id="main" href="index.html">Main</a> 
    <a id="information" class="bonus" href="information.html" >Statistics</a>
    <a id="contacts" class="bonus" href="contacts.html" style="background-color:#bad455">Contacts</a>
    <a id="media" class="bonus" href="media.html">Media</a>
    <a id="logout" href="logout.html">Log out</a>
    
</div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="contacts">
<h4 class="font">Contacts</h4>
<div id="fullcontacts">
  <a class="twitter-timeline float" data-width="300" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<h3>Contacts: Friends of Karura Forest Community Forest Association</h3>
<p>We would encourage you to become more than just a visitor to Karura. Please help to protect the forest by becoming a Friend.</p>
<h3>Membership & Administrative Enquiries</h3>
<p>Lucy Njoka: +254 (0)739 262092 or +254 (0)791 398371</p>
<a href="mailto:lnjoka@karurafriends.org">lnjoka@karurafriends.org</a>
<p>Admin Matters:<a href="mailto:info@karurafriends.org"> info@karurafriends.org</p></a>
<h3 class="onlyh3">Events & General Enquiries</h3>
<p>Lucy Njoka: +254 (0)739 262092 or +254 (0)791 398371</p>
<a href="mailto:lnjoka@karurafriends.org">lnjoka@karurafriends.org</a>
<p>John Chege, Chief Scout: +254 (0)724 215423</p>
<a href="mailto:jchege@karurafriends.org">jchege@karurafriends.org</a>
<p>Peter Njui, Security & Infrastructure: +254 (0)722 846264</p>
<a href="mailto:peter.njui@ke.g4s.com">peter.njui@ke.g4s.com</a>
<p><h3 class="onlyh3"><span style="font-weight:bold">PKF</span> e-mails</h3></p>
<p>General Enquiries:<a class="pls" href="mailto:"info@karurafriends.org">info@karurafriends.org</a>
<p>Comments & suggestions:<a  class="pls"href="mailto:rafiki@karurafriends.org">rafiki@karurafriends.org</a></p>
<h3 class="onlyh3">More Useful Numbers</h3>

<div class="kenya">
  <p style="font-weight:bold">Kenya Forest Service</p>
  <p>John Orwa, Chief Forester. . . . . . . . . . .  0727 818963</p>
  <p>Fredrick Mutisya, Forester . . . . . . . . . .  0722 581402</p>
  <p>Corporal Okoth . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  0721 483017</p>
  <p>Sergeant Catherine . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  0725 370990</p>
  <p> Ag RC Dickson Njiru. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  0721 586793</p>
</div>

<div s class="Karura">
  <p style="font-weight:bold" margin-top:50px">Friends of Karura Forest</p>
  <p>John Chege, Chief Scout  . . . . . . . . . . .  0724 215423</p>
  <p>Peter Kamau, Dep. Chief Scout. . . . . . . . .  0720 350206</p>
  <p>Peter Njui, G4S. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  0722 846264</p>
  <p>Karanja Njoroge, KFK Chair . . . . . . . . . .  0729 030301</p>
  <p>Cristina Boelcke-Croze, Vice-Chair . . . . . .  0702 633613</p>
  <p>Chantal Mariotte, Projects . . . . . . . . . .  0791 398371</p>
</div>

<div class="note">
  <p>Please make a note of these numbers and carry your mobile with you. Keep to the marked trails and exercise caution particularly when they are wet and slippery. Note that mobile reception is virtually non-existent along the Karura River between the Mau-Mau Caves and  the Waterfall.  Buy a map to know where you are in the forest. </p>
</div>


  <h3>Maps</h3>
  <p class="note">The New Revised Karura Forest Map is now out, showing all tracks, junctions and main forest features. Only 200/=, at main gates, K.F.E.E.T. Centre or administrative office at Triad House, 83 Muthaiga Road, Old Muthaiga.</p>
  <p>An illustrated list of main bird species is available F.O.C.</p>
  <p style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold" >Opening hours: 06:00 AM to 18:00 PM</p>
 <div class="flexbox">
  
   <p>Friends of Karura Forest<Br>
Community Forest Association<br>
PO Box 63402-00619<br>
83 Triad House<br>
Limuru Road<br>
Muthaiga, Nairobi<br>
General Enquiries: +254 (0) 722 891 654<br>
rafiki@karurafriends.org<br>
info@karurafriends.org<br>
www.karurafriends.org<br></p>
 </div>


<div  class="forms">
<h3 class="only">Contact us</h3>
<form>
<label for="firstname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required placeholder="Enter your name" required=><br>
<label for="secondname">Second name:</label>
<input type="name" id="secondname" name="secondname" required placeholder="Enter second name"><br>
<label for="email">Enter your email here:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="mail" placeholder="Enter your email here" required><br>
<input  type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</main>
  

  
</body>
```

Hello, I've got a problem. Right now I'm trying to iframe a twitter website but I want it to be pushed to the right side of the website. The thing is when I refresh the page it shows iframe on the right side as it is supposed to, but when the page finishes loading, it goes back to its default place. I'm not sure what happens here.  I've already tried margin-left:auto  and float:right  , but none of these worked.

P.S the code might not be shown properly so I made a jsfiddle  where u can clearly see it moving back to its original place.  https://jsfiddle.net/zkxb9n4r/ . Would be really grateful if someone helps me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the target for the iFrame in a div that applies the floating:

```
 <div class="float">
   <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="300" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a>
</div>
...
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

See an updated jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/zkxb9n4r/6/

Comment: Thank you so much!!